# Visual C# Error: System.Windows.Forms.Button does not contain a definition for ToInt32

Tags: c#

Im working on a `decimal` to `binary converter` that works perfectly on a console and then i get these errors about my core math operations:

`System.Windows.Forms.Button` does not contain a definition for `ToInt32` and no extension method `ToInt32` accepting a first argument of type `System.Windows.Forms.Button` could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) 
Line:93

No overload for method 'ToString' takes 2 arguments Line:94

System.Windows.Forms.Button does not contain a definition for 'ToInt32' and no extension method 'ToInt32' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.Button' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) Line:103

Here is the code:

```
    public void Convert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string Input;
        bool IsNotBinary;
        string Answer;
        Start:
        Input = UserInput.Text;
        int InputLength = Input.Length;
        if (InputLength > 10)
        {
            UserInput.Text = "Overflow";
            goto Start;
        }
        int Int;
        bool IsANumber = int.TryParse(Input, out Int);
        if (IsANumber == false)
        {
            UserInput.Text = "Invalid Character";
            goto Start;
        }
        IsNotBinary = Input.Contains("3");
        if (IsNotBinary == true)
        {
            goto End;

        }
        IsNotBinary = Input.Contains("4");
        if (IsNotBinary == true)
        {
            goto End;

        }
        IsNotBinary = Input.Contains("5");
        if (IsNotBinary == true)
        {
            goto End;

        }
        IsNotBinary = Input.Contains("6");
        if (IsNotBinary == true)
        {
            goto End;

        }
        IsNotBinary = Input.Contains("7");
        if (IsNotBinary == true)
        {
            goto End;

        }
        IsNotBinary = Input.Contains("8");
        if (IsNotBinary == true)
        {
            goto End;

        }
        IsNotBinary = Input.Contains("9");
    End:

        if (IsNotBinary == true)
        {

            // decimal to binary
            int InputInt = Convert.ToInt32(Input); // converts the string "Input" to the int "InputInt"
            Answer = Convert.ToString(InputInt, 2);
            UserInput.Text = Answer;

        }

        else
        {

            // binary to decimal
            Answer = Convert.ToInt32(Input, 2).ToString();
            UserInput.Text = Answer;

        }
        Console.ReadLine();
        goto Start;
    }

    public void QuitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }        
}
```

}

Comment: Can you show us exactly where this is blowing up? My thoughts are that you've called a button control "Convert" which will throw this off. Changing the name of your button may help. Also: avoid the use of "goto".. there are close to ZERO needs for it and makes the code hard to follow.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error message is quite clear:

> System.Windows.Forms.Button' does not contain a definition for 'ToInt32'

My psychic debugger tells me that you have a class level button variable named `Convert`, so you're not calling the `ToInt32` method on the static `Convert` class as your button is hiding it.  Either rename the button or fully qualify the name, i.e., `System.Convert.ToInt32()`.

Edit:

Ok, I guess I didn't need my psychic debugger after all.  Your event handler tells me all I need to know:

```
public void Convert_Click(...)
```

Comment: Oh god I said the same thing before looking at the event handler.. lol.

Comment: Thank You i renamed my Convert class and it works :D i love the coding community